# Scala type mismatch error time conversion program

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala as it's what's taught for the intro CS course at my school. I'm unsure as to why I'm getting this error:

```
/home/ubuntu/Documents/Scala/Self/timeConvertIf.scala:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Int
    val finalString = displayHours+":"("0"*(2-min.length))+min+":"+("0"*(2-sec.length))+sec
                                              ^
one error found
```

Code:

```
import io.StdIn._
print("Enter the number of seconds. ")
val totalSeconds = readInt()

if (totalSeconds > 0) {
    val displaySeconds = totalSeconds%60
    val totalMinutes = totalSeconds/60
    val displayMinutes = totalMinutes%60
    val displayHours = totalMinutes/60
    val sec = displaySeconds.toString
    val min = displayMinutes.toString
    val finalString = displayHours+":"("0"*(2-min.length))+min+":"+("0"*(2-sec.length))+sec
    println(finalString)
}
else {
    println("This only works for a positive number of seconds.")
}
```

I understand what a type mismatch error is, but I don't know why I'm getting the error where the error shows up. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to explain why you are getting this "weird" error message.

If you indent it a little bit, and leave some space
between the tokens, you can see it much better:

```
import io.StdIn._
print("Enter the number of seconds. ")
val totalSeconds = 3600 // readInt()

if (totalSeconds > 0) {
  val displaySeconds = totalSeconds % 60
  val totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60
  val displayMinutes = totalMinutes % 60
  val displayHours = totalMinutes / 60
  val sec = displaySeconds.toString
  val min = displayMinutes.toString
  val finalString = 
    displayHours + ":" + // <---- you missed this '+'
    ("0" * (2 - min.length)) + min + ":" + 
    ("0" * (2 - sec.length)) + sec
  println(finalString)
} else {
  println("This only works for a positive number of seconds.")
}
```

What happened is: you forgot `+` and instead wrote down the expression `":" (foo)`, where `foo` was of type String.
Now, the compiler desugared it into the method application `":".apply(foo)` (it always does it, if you write down
something like `f(x)`, where `f` is not a method). The method `apply` does not exist on a `String`, but it *does*
exist on an "pimped" `RichString`, to which the string `":"` is automatically converted. The method `apply(i: Int)`
on `RichString` expects an integer `i`, and returns the `i`-th character of the string. This is why you got the error message
*"required Int but found String"*.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much for the thorough explanation. Help'd alot!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one `+` between the first `":"` and `("0" * (2 - min.length))`:

```
val finalString = displayHours + ":" + ("0" * (2 - min.length)) + min + ":" + ("0" * (2 - sec.length)) + sec
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `+` in front of `("0"*(2-min.length))`:

```
val finalString = displayHours + ":" + ("0"*(2-min.length)) + min + 
                                 ":" + ("0"*(2-sec.length)) + sec
```

You could also use `f"$num%02d"` number-formatting as follows:

```
val finalString = f"${displayHours}:${displayMinutes}%02d:${displaySeconds}%02d"
```